# how to do a batch query to the G+ Domains API with the python client

Tags: google-api, google-plus

Here there is documentation on how to do it in raw HTTP, is it possible to do it with the python client? If so, can someone provide a simple example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yup, the python client supports batch requests, see the documentation here:
https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/batch

Here a simple example specific for the domains API:

```
from apiclient.discovery import build
from apiclient.http import BatchHttpRequest

service = build('plus', 'v1domains')

batch = BatchHttpRequest(callback=my_callback)

batch.add(service.circles().addPeople(circleId=circle_id, userId=user_id1))
batch.add(service.circles().addPeople(circleId=circle_id, userId=user_id2))
batch.add(service.circles().addPeople(circleId=circle_id, userId=user_id3))

batch.execute(http=http)
```

One important thing to note about batch requests is that each request in the batch will still count against the API quota.

Comment: Also, feel free to check out https://developers.google.com/+/domains/batch to learn more about the structure of batch requests, in general.

Comment: Where is the 'build' function? Where is it in imports?

Comment: @Ares - added the missing import to my answer